# How to translate ABM Model from MATLAB to NetLogo?

Tags: matlab, netlogo

Is there any method to translate MATLAB ABM model to NetLogo? I want to make changes in an existing MATLAB Model by importing it in Netlogo. I have no know-how about MATLAB.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, no. There is an extension (see https://github.com/mbi2gs/netlogo-matlab-extension/wiki) to, for example, transfer variable values between Matlab and NetLogo, but there is no way to turn Matlab code into NetLogo code.